# Laravel получить отдельно параметры POST и GET

Tags: php, laravel, requests, guzzle

К нам на контроллер приходит запрос $request. Мы хотим изменить url, некоторые параметры в header.
Проблема в том, что $request->all() выдает все параметры и POST и GET вместе, не разделяя.
Потому при формировании нового запроса

```
$client = new GClient();
$response = $client->request($new_method, $new_url, $params);
```

Непонятно какие параметры вставлять в массив $param['query'] - для GET параметров, а какие вставлять в $param['form_params'] для POST параметров.

Comment: воспользуетесь не `all()` а например `query()`

Comment: Тест показал, что query() выдает GET параметры, post() - POST соответственно. Есть какие-то нюансы?

Comment: Почему не посмотреть сорцы как это работает? Там все четко: `class Request ...  /** Request body parameters ($_POST).*/ public $request; /** Query string parameters ($_GET).*/ public $query;`. Сорцы лежат в vendor. [Содержимое класса](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/5.4/Request.php). Поэтому используйте `$request->request->all();` для POST и `$request->query->all();` для GET

Comment: @TotalPusher, я обычно спрашиваю может кто из гуру в курсе, исходники это уже от безысходности) Спасибо)

Comment: Почему от безысходности? Это - первый путь. Взяли в своей IDE, щелкнули по `$request->all()`, попали в сорцы. В сорцах содержится даже больше информации, чем в документации, пояснены многие нюансы. Я сделал именно так. Не "щелкается" в IDE? Значит ее нужно настроить.

Answer (score -1):

```
$request->get();
$request->post();
```

Comment: $request->get();
Должен на вход принимать параметры, так что не верно.